# Executing SSIS 2012 package that has script components from external application

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm writing an application that will execute an SSIS 2012 package using the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS v 11.0 assembly. The package that I'm trying to execute was designed and successfully executed from SSDT-2012, and has script components that handle rows that don't transfer correctly.

When I try to run my application I get the error message for each of my script components:

SSIS.Pipeline: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install [Script Component Name] of Integration Services or higher.

Configuration: Building application for x86 on Windows with the following app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

The only relevant code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
class MyApp
{
    public void ExecutePackage()
    {
        //Assume I have all the variables I need like packageFile, packageName, 
        //srcConnectionString, destConnectionString and eventListener etc.

        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResults pkgResults;

        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageFile, eventListener);

        pkg.Variables["SrcConnectionString"].Value = srcConnectionString;
        pkg.Variables["DestConnectionString"].Value = destConnectionString;

        if (null != srcAssembly || null != destAssembly)
        {
            foreach (ConnectionManager connection in pkg.Connections)
            {
                if (null != srcAssembly && connection.Name.Contains("Source"))
                {
                    connection.SetQualifier(srcAssembly);
                }
                else if (null != destAssembly && connection.Name.Contains("Destination"))
                {
                    connection.SetQualifier(destAssembly);
                }
            }
        }

        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have the SQL Server Integration Services Service installed on the machine the application is running from.

See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks! That is kind of a ridiculous error message though :/