# To run SSIS package outside of SQL server Data Tools you must install File_creation of Integration services or higher

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Getting this error while trying to run Package.dtsx from command file(`.cmd`).

> To run SSIS package outside of SQL server Data Tools you must install %File_creation% of Integration services or higher

I've used package parameters & File System Tasks in the package. I used below script in command file.

```
DTEXEC /FILE "F:\SOME FOLDER\Package.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "F:\SOME FOLDER\PackagedtsConfig"
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469249/to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install-move-fil#39553924

Comment: What version of SQL Server (express/standard/enterprise) and what year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that SSIS packages are deployed using a SSDT version newer that the one installed on the server you are trying to execute the package on it. You have to install the same version of SSDT on the server.

**Useful Links**

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5a149bf-a636-44bd-b825-36f9984ae720/to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install-move-file-to-archive-of?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138850/ssis-to-run-the-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install-expre

Comment: @user2919579 if it solved your issue you have to [accept or upvote this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), else give me a feedback