# Conditional Split not working when running SSIS package from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSIS package that works fine from VS2015 but when I try to run it from SSMS it fails with the error:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server you must install
>   conditional split of integration services or higher.

I did a little research and also created a new package with only a source and destination which worked fine. Once I added the conditional split it failed again. It seems like this may be a version conflict between the data tools, SSIS and SQL Server. I have other packages with conditional splits and other tasks that are executed in SQL Server such as Execute SQL tasks. The only reason I can think that they work is because they were created in a previous version of SSIS then upgraded.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community with 
SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61021.0 (SQL Server 2016 version which is backward compatible)
SQL Server Integration Services Designer 13.0.1701.8

On the SQL Server it says the SSIS version is 12.0.2269

My version of management Studio is 12.0.2000.8

Any ideas on what might be causing this error?

Comment: I noticed when comparing the package to some of the older ones that were created in a previous version then upgraded that some of the project properties were different. I set it to package deployment model and changed the StartObjectID to <Active Package> but as expected that had no change on the situation.

Comment: What is the target version of the project that contains your SSIS package?

Comment: [SSIS isn't installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882258/executing-ssis-2012-package-that-has-script-components-from-external-application) is the usual source of "you must install X of integration services or higher" errors. It sounds like you have a bit of a mashup of versions so you'll want to make sure the VS project is targeting 2014 and not the default of 2016

Comment: Also, 12.00.2269 is pretty far out of date for patching. Likely unrelated to your issue but you/your admin should look at [patching that box](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2014) Current version is SP2/CU4 and you're on essentially RTM

Comment: So I was trying to import the package from the file system. Once I created an SSIS catalog I was able to deploy the package and execute it from the catalog.