# Running SSIS automatically with pat file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014-express

I created an SSIS package in visual studio 2015 with a couple SQL execute tasks, a data flow task and a script task. Since I am using SQL Server 2014 Express edition, I want to be able to schedule running the package using a pat file.

What I found is that the package runs just fine using a pat file without the script task on it but fails(see image below) when I add the script task back on the package. Would anyone know how to run an SSIS package that contains a script task using a pat file? Your help and time is appreciated

Question is not a duplicate because in my case package can be run with a pat file when script task is excluded.

[SSIS package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PxAC.png).

[image: Error in CMD]

[image: PAT]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing SSIS 2012 package that has script components from external application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882258/executing-ssis-2012-package-that-has-script-components-from-external-application)

Comment: Do either of the answers here help?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469249/to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install-move-fil    I'm suspicious that you've tagged VS2015 and SQL Server 2014.   They are not compatible by default.

Comment: BTW, SQL 2014 Express Edition does not contain SSIS functionality. You could try using 2014 Developer edition, which is free, but is obviously only licensed for development use. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/run-integration-services-ssis-packages?view=sql-server-2014 for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out in blog below the specific answer to my question. It turns out you can only run SSIS packages with simpler component using a pat file. If you package contains a script task, script components or other components of the like the execution will fail. Enjoy !!

[blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/10/28/running-ssis-packages-outside-the-developer-tools-using-dtexec-exe-without-installing-the-integration-services/)